# ASP.NET variable that increases when button is clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm building a quiz and I want to make it so only one question appears at a time. I'm using ASP.NET c#. I thought a good way to do this would be using a public int that grows every time the form is submitted, and depending on the value of the public int a certain question is displayed. Only problem is the form seems to stop submitting after one click so the int doesn't grow. Any way to bypass this issue? Thanks!

this is my html code (not the entire quiz as it's pretty long):

```
    <form id="quiz" name="quiz" method="post" runat="server">
<%if (qCounter == 0)
    { %>
       <p id="cap"> what best describes your dream home decor?</p><br />
       <asp:RadioButton ID="chic1" name="home" runat="server" /><label>minimalist with splashes of color and your favorite art prints hanging on the wall</label><br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="urban1" name="home" runat="server" /><label>exposed brick, cement floors, hanging plants and a yellow teapot</label><br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="grunge1" name="home" runat="server" /><label>a loft with a wall full of posters, fairy lights, a place to display a record collection</label><br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="vintage1" name="home" runat="server" /><label>a cozy vibe, patterns and warm colors, maybe a stained glass window</label><br />

<%}
    else if (qCounter == 1)
    { %>
               <p id="cap"> If we opened your closet what color pallet would we find?</p><br />
       <asp:RadioButton ID="neutral1" name="color" runat="server" /><label>basics such as navy white khaki charcoal or brown</label><br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="pastel1" name="color" runat="server" /><label>lots of white and pastel colors</label><br />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="color1" name="color" runat="server" /><label>a rainbow of colors</label><br />
<%}
    </form>
```

and this is my C# code (on code behind)

```
 public int qCounter;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    qCounter = 0;
    if (Request.Form["sub"] != null)
    {
        Response.Write(qCounter);
        qCounter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to persist the old value somewhere since ASP.NET doesn`t store any variables or controls. Everything gets disposed at the end of the current life-cycle(when the HTML was sent to the client). You could use the session or the ViewState.

Comment: You need to lean about the [page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). You can't just store data in a field. Every time the page is requested (either initially or via postback) the page class is recreated. Meaning you lose any state you stored in fields or properties. You need to store your state somewhere more persistent. Also, don't write directly to the response. You have little control over where the values end up. Add a label to your page and update the label test.